# Single page view not loading Images from layout

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

So upon clicking on the link to see a single view, The page breaks and does not load my images.

Layout working fine
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Th5Fd.png

Layout broken
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiEhh.png

Link to route

```
{{URL::route('post',$post->id)}}
```

Post Controller

```
public function getPost($id = null)
{
    return View::make('index.post')
      ->with('post',Post::find($id)
      ->with('title','Post');
}
```

Route

```
  `Route::get('post/{id},array('as'=>'post','uses'=>'PostsController@getPost'));`
```

Any help would be appreciated this problem is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best guess with the limited information, is that you have the url's to the images relative and not absolute.

so you are linking to you images with something like

```
<img src="images/layout/header1.jpg" />
```

when you should be using

```
<img src="/images/layout/header1.jpg" />
```

Comment: I can't even upvote but thanks!  Its always the littlest thing.